# req.session is undefined in another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm trying to create a simple login application, for which i wanna store session of logged in user. But everytime i'm trying to access the req.session in another module it says undefined where as the values are set to it already.

Following is my code.

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , login = require('./routes/login')
  , userInfo = require('./routes/userInfo')
  , MemoryStore = new express.session.MemoryStore()
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7272);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
      store : MemoryStore,
      secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
      duration: 30 * 60 * 1000
}));
app.use(routes);
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
            'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        next();
});
app.use(app.router);

// development only
if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/login', login.afterLogin);
app.get('/userInfo', userInfo.userInfo);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

login.js

```
 var usrname, paswd;

    var ejs = require("ejs");
    var mysql = require("./mysql");
    var jwt = require('jwt-simple');

    function afterLogin (req, res) {
        var getU = "SQL Query";

        mysql.fetch(function(err,results){
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                if (results.length > 0){
                    req.session.usrname = req.param("username");
                    res.send({
                        "login":"Success",
                        "error" : "none"
                    });
                } else {        
                    res.json({
                        "login":"Fail",
                        "error" : "User Not Valid"
                    });
                }
            }
        }, getU);
    }

    exports.afterLogin = afterLogin;
```

Here the value is stored in session variable

But as I try to retrieve this value in another module it says undefined

userInfo.js

```
var mysql = require("./mysql");

function userInfo (req, res) {
    console.log("Session Store : : " + req.session.usrname); // this is undefined

    var getUser = "Some SQL Query";

    mysql.fetch(function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            if (results.length > 0){
                res.json({
                  "status":"Success",
                  "error" : "none"
                });

            } else {
                res.json({
                    "status":"fail",
                    "error" : "User Not Valid"
                });
            }
        }
    }, getUser);
}

exports.userInfo = userInfo;
```

Comment: I see, that you assign req.session.usrname, but not req.session.token

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to display usrname, still i'm facing the same issue